# Endfloat document with list of figures and no figures

Tags: floats, lists, endfloat

I am using the package endfloat to place all figures to the end of the document. I would like to generate the list of figures but not the figures themselves. The best that I can piece together from answers found on this site is:

```
% Places all the figures after the references and generates a list of references
\usepackage[figuresonly,nomarkers]{endfloat}        
% Used to reformat the list of figures
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}                            
%the previous line resets it
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}                                                      
% To delete the list of figures and figures genereated after the references     
\nofiles\renewcommand{\processdelayedfloats}{}
```

and before the end of my document I have the following to remove page numbers from the list:

```
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
```

This method removes the list of figures too. I would like to keep all the references and hyperlinks. Want I want to do is to stop the document after the list of figures. This has to be done in the Latex code itself and not retrospectively.

Comment: You might also look at \includeonly

Answer (score 1):

Actually it turns out that this was trivial. I just placed `\listoffigures` after the `\pagenumbering{gobble}` command.